# How to use z3 in a flutter plugin

Tags: flutter, z3, flutter-plugin

I would like to use `z3` within a Flutter plugin but I cannot managed to have even a basic plugin compiled. Currently I can create a simple plugin using `Android Studio` and all works fine. I can add `z3` as an external dependency manually and use it within my code. The problem is that when I try to generate the `apk` I have the following error:

```
error: package com.microsoft.z3 does not exist
```

I cannot understand why this happens considering that within the IDE I can use the package and I added it in as an external library.

In order to double check what I'm doing, I tried to create a new project using `z3` and all worked fine.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for that error: just update your `build.gradle` adding the following section:

```
dependencies {
    implementation files('libs/com.microsoft.z3.jar')
}
```

Of course inside `android/libs` you need to copy the `jar` file

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer, to indicate that the problem has been solved